# How to select an iframe as soon as it appears on the screen in python

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, webdriverwait

*I am trying to fill data inside an iframe
But the iframe appears anywhere between 15-30 seconds*

*I have used time.sleep(30)- Works well if the iframe loads at around 25-30 seconds.
But sometimes it loads up at 15 seconds and the remaining 15 seconds are wasted*

*I don't wanna waste time with explicit sleep
Is there any other way I can perform action on iframe as soon as it appears in the viewport?*

**My Code:**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit'][contains(.,'Submit')]").click()
time.sleep(30)
        
iframe = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
driver.switch_to_frame(iframe[3])
driver.find_element_by_xpath("something").send_keys()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(something).click()
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use webdriverwait as following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"(//iframe)[3]")))


driver.find_element_by_xpath("something").send_keys()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(something).click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use that with Explicit waits  :

**Sample code  :**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
iframe = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((iframe[3])))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("something").send_keys()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(something).click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Official docs about [Explicit waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)

Note that `switch_to_default_content()` has been deprecated. you will have to use `driver.switch_to.default_content()` instead.